# Sharepoint tasks - ASSIGNED TO value is empty

Tags: column

I created custom view in sharepoint 2013 for tasks. So users can see only tasks which are created by them or assigned by them. They all have contribute rights, and I remove abillity to create custom views for them.

Problem is that when user create and asign task to other user, assigned to field is empty, but task is still being assigned. Also user to who is task asigned, cannot see who created task..

Site owner can see those fields.

[image]

I inspected missing elements, this is output:

[image: Missing element]

Not shure what it does mean. I also checked console for errors, there aren't any of them. Default text color is different from background.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. For those with same problem here is the solution.

**Site settings - people and group - select problematic group - Settings - List Settings - Advanced settings - Read access: Read ALL**

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it looks like there's only one view "My Tasks". Did you modify that view? You have to reselect the view (from web part properties on the page) once you make changes to the view. Also, check your filters on the view. See if matches the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I modified that one. Tried to reselect the view, but nothing changes. In my admin account, I have view all tasks, in which I can see al tasks created by users, everything there is ok, I can see assigned to and created by values. I also checked filters on view, it's same as yours. But it shouldn't make any diference anyway, it only shows tasks, not the value of fields :)

Comment: Do you see AssignedTo/Created By on the detail page of the task?

Comment: No, I don't see it on the detail page of the task either. ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/S4BfB.jpg) ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vc3Ux.jpg)

Comment: Open up Firebug/IE tools to inspect those missing elements. Also check your console for any errors. See if default color for the text (like visited link) is not same as background color (black).

Comment: Will try that, but not shure about this. My admin user can see all values, I also tried to give those users full permision, but they still couldn't see it. ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7sVid.jpg)